# Obtaining the position of the mouse on the form for a button object

Tags: c#, button

Although I posted something related to this (which cost me many down-votes), I decided to continue with my original attempt to do it by myself (with some good results), but I bumped into a problem, and I cannot see how to solve it.

My code creates a set of *n* clickable buttons, which should be moved when pressed the button.  I already managed to do it, but when i click it and move them, they "jump" in a weird manner, not repositioning how I want them to, and then they can be moved freely.

This is the code of the button class:

```
namespace moverButtons 
{
    class buttonCito:Button
    {

        Point posActual;
        bool mousePressed;

       // public MouseEventHandler MouseMove;
        public buttonCito(int altUra, int anchUra, Point position)
        {
            this.Height = altUra;
            this.Width = anchUra;
            this.Location = position;

        }

        public buttonCito()
        {
            // TO DO: Complete member initialization
        }

        protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            mousePressed = (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) ? true : false;

            if (e.Location != null && mousePressed)
            {
                    moverButton(e.X, e.Y);

            }        

            //Añadir rutina para mover con el mouse 
            //Add routine to move with the mouse
        }
        public void moverButton(int x,int y)
        {

            this.Location = new Point(x + posActual.X, y + posActual.Y);
            posActual = this.Location;
        }

    }
}
```

And this is the code of the form:

```
namespace moverbuttons

{   
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Point positionMouseForm;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(map_MouseMove);

        }

        private void map_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)//obtains the position of the mouse on the form
        {   //I want to give this position to the button class, is there  a way?
            positionMouseForm = e.Location;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   List<buttonCito> buttons = new List<buttonCito>();
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int x,y;

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                x = rnd.Next(1, 300);
                y = rnd.Next(1, 300);
                buttonCito newButton = new buttonCito(50,50,new Point(x,y));


                buttons.Add(newButton);
                this.Controls.Add(newButton);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If could, somehow give the position of the mouse on the form to the buttons, I could easily fix it.

Comment: You may want to review the help center on [creating a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). No one wants to climb through a mountain of code.

Comment: Well the code is pretty short, i used a lot of "using" just in case, and spaces.

Comment: Its not quite clear what is wrong with the posted code (especially given that there is so much of it). You say it "jumps", and then "can move freely". What on earth does that mean? Can you give an example? Btw, thank you for posting code, too much is way better than none :)

Comment: The code may be short, but formatting is important. We read a TON of questions every day, and if it looks like its going to take 10 minutes just to read the question, many will skip it.

Comment: well, you see, i click them in order to move them, their "origin point" becomes the tip of the cursor (which i do not want) and then i can move them, but with the inner cursor position changed, i want if for example i click the button, the position of the cursor inside the button remains the same, and then i move the button, with the same position of the cursor inside the button (sorry if it sounded messy, im not a native english speaker).

Comment: So you want to forcibly move the cursor to this new random position with the button? That doesn't seem like a good idea. I still don't understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I think i just need to obtain the position of the mouse on the form to the buttons, it would just be a piece of cake, but i do not know how to give it on runtime.

Comment: Ok, just to be clear, you want the position of the cursor relative to the origin (upper left corner) of the button?

Comment: @LordTakkera, no, the otherwise, to move the button with the cursor of the mouse, but with the position of the cursor inside the button unchanged. cause with my code, its "inner" position changes when i move it

Comment: @LordTakkera sorry you posted when i was typing,

Comment: I think I finally understand, hopefully my answer helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to approach this problem would be to use a delta (the difference between two objects).

```
Point lastMousePosition;

private void MoveButton(int currentX, int currentY)
{
     int deltaX = currentX - lastMousePosition.X;
     int deltaY = currentY - lastMousePosition.Y;

     this.Location = new Point(Location.X + deltaX, Location.Y + deltaY);
     lastMousePosition = new Point(currentX, currentY);
}
```

You would set lastMousePosition initially to the mouse position when the button is pressed (and not again until it is released).

Note that repeatedly calling constructors like this is not very performant. You may want to consider reusing a Point object you instantiate only once. Of course you should only worry about that once you have eveything working :)

Comment: Omg it works, you are a genius!!, how is this technique called? i remember i saw it in a code i read a while ago now that i recall, but i didnt know what it was for. thanks a lot

Comment: I'm not sure there is a special name for it, but moving things around using deltas is pretty common in game programming (and dynamic UI programming in general). When I do it I just say I'm "using a delta".

Comment: Delta, btw, is a greek letter used in all sorts of fields to represent the change or difference in the state of an object.